# How long would an SD Card using NTFS last in comparison to one using FAT32

Tags: filesystems, ntfs, storage, sd-card, fat32

I'm looking to use a 512GB SD card to expand my laptop storage and I've seen everywhere that an SD Card using NTFS will more quickly use up its write cycles because of journaling.

How exactly does this journaling work? If I store an NTFS card without inserting it into a computer would it still last shorter than a FAT32 card?

Answer (score 1):

> How exactly does this journaling work?

Journaling is a feature that keeps filesystem consistent in case of interrupted write, for example due to power loss.

When data is expected to be written to filesystem, it's first written to the journal. Then actual write to the target destination is executed and the journal entry is marked as written.

- If the journal write is interrupted, next time the filesystem is initialized the partially written journal entry will be discarded and filesystem will remain consistent as if the write didn't happen.
- If destination write is interrupted, the next time the now-inconsistent filesystem is initialized its driver will find a journal entry not marked as flushed. It will read the journal entry and attempt to write it to its destination again, restoring filesystem consistency.

This scheme increases reliability, but doubles number of writes required to make changes to disk. Since flash-based media have limited write endurance, use of journaled filesystems will reduce their lifespan.

> If I store an NTFS card without inserting it into a computer would it still last shorter than a FAT32 card?

Filesystems - even sophisticated ones - are just data structures. An SD card has no understanding of what filesystem is stored on it, it's just a bunch of ordered bytes. It doesn't matter what bytes you have on your SD card and if they make up some kind of filesystem. It's how that data can be interacted with that affects media lifespan. Flash media are write-limited, so the more you write to them (the more writes a filesystem requires), the faster you're wearing them out.